# how to make this type textField? (check image)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, textfield

[image]

How to make text typed in TextField undeletable?
I am fairly new to programming, after looking around I thought that id takes my chances with asking here. I basically need textField like the picture.

Comment: You shoud use `Text` if you want it to be undeletable, or add `enable:false` in `TextField`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your text `readOnly: true`

```
DottedBorder(
  color: Colors.black,
  strokeWidth: 1,
  child:   Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.tealAccent,
    ),
    child: TextField(
      readOnly: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
        hintText: 'Search your trips',
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: but how to make this doted border on text field.

Comment: you can try with dotted_border https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border

Comment: update my answer, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to archive using [dotted_border](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border)

[image]

**Code**

```dart
 DottedBorder(
          color: Colors.grey,
          dashPattern: [2, 3, 2, 3],
          strokeWidth: 1,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text(
            "Basic Maths",
          )),
```